# How to bypass Serial port libraries in Arduino

Tags: arduino

I want to write my own code for managing an Arduino serial port (9bit serial) so I need to bypass the preprogrammed arduino ISR vector for Serial1 TX. I can do that by modifying HardwareSerial1.cpp but I dislike the fact that my code becomes non portable and a potential victim of library updates.

Do you know how to program a different ISR vector without messing into library code?  I tried this in my own code to no avail:

```
//bypass arduino library for serial 1 and use this ISR instead
ISR(UART1_UDRE_vect) 
{ 
    9bitSerial.interrupt(); 
}
```

The following error is reported, which seems to confirm the approach doesn't work:

ISR.cpp:11:25: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
ISR.cpp:in expansion of macro 'UART1_UDRE_vect'

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safest way, IMHO, is to copy the entire `HardwareSerial` class to a differently-named class.  Then proceed to make your modifications.  This is exactly what I did for [NeoHWSerial](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoHWSerial) and [NeoICSerial](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoICSerial): they are copied and renamed from `HardwareSerial` and `AltSoftSerial`.

However, all uses of `Serialx` (instances of `HardwareSerial`) in a build must be replaced with instances of your class.  You won't be able to mix instances of HardwareSerial with your class (duplicate ISR errors).  But that's no big deal if your class only *adds* behavior.  Other instances that don't use 9 bits should not be affected.  If you don't mind, I'd be interested in folding those changes into NeoHWSerial.  I've been occasionally looking at 9-bit serial for NeoSWSerial, too.

Comment: So are you saying harwareserial ISR vectors are declared at build time only if any part of the firmware is calling Serialx?
I could easily copy the whole library and rename it.
I can share my code if you want (after I make a cleanup), but take note that I'm using it for a very specific purpose: sending Seatalk messages, which only sets the 9th bit on the first byte being sent, so it's far from being universal, but a simple mod would do it.

Comment: Yes, any reference to a `HardwareSerial` *thing* (e.g. `Serial2`) will cause the linker to include the `HardwareSerial` ISRs.  The linker will complain about the same ISRs being in your new class.  So you must copy the whole library, rename it (the file, the class name, *and* instances of that class), modify it, and eliminate all `HardwareSerial` references in your sketch.  Include your new class file and use your new class for regular printing: `MySerial.print`.

Comment: This is great, that answers my question. How can I send you my code? Looks like I cannot do it in this thread unless I create a mess.

Comment: Post it as a github repository, then put a link to that repo here.  Here's two ways to do it: (1) use the site to create the repo, create files in that repo, then cut&paste text from your files into the github editor (browser); or (2) install the "github for Windows" app (GfW), create a new repo (locally), copy your files into the new github subdirectory, "commit" those changes in GfW, and "sync" that commit with your github account (remote).  Then you should be able to see it on the github site, under your account. It's a great way to give back to the community that helped you, too.